# Нужно спарсенные данные перевести в Excel таблицу

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


headres = {"accept": "*/*",
           "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36"}


base_url = "https://www.samgups.ru/pod/umu/raspisanie/2019-2020/pervyy-semestr/HTML/10.htm"


def cmp_parse(base_url, headers):
    session = requests.Session()
    request = session.get(base_url, headers=headers)
    if request.status_code == 200:
        soup = bs(request.content, 'html.parser')
        print(soup)
    else:
        print("ERROR")


cmp_parse(base_url, headres)
```

Comment: Не могу спарсенные данные записать в excel. Читал документалки библиотек смотрел видосы но так и не смог вывести данные в excel таблицу

Comment: `>> Не могу спарсенные данные записать в excel` не видно чтобы в коде вы с экселем работали. Вот вам пример создания экселя: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/a0fc6877ab058b59110757758e5eba28e170c58e/office__excel__openpyxl__xlwt/xls__xlwt__hello_world.py#L7

Comment: Мне помогла статья: https://tokmakov.msk.ru/blog/item/71

Answer (score 0):

```js
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import xlwt

headres = {"accept": "*/*",
           "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36"}
base_url = "https://www.samgups.ru/pod/umu/raspisanie/2019-2020/pervyy-semestr/HTML/10.htm"

def cmp_parse(base_url, headers):
    sl = []
    session = requests.Session()
    request = session.get(base_url, headers=headers)
    if request.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(request.content, 'html.parser', from_encoding = 'cp1251')
        print(soup)
        tit = soup.body.find('p')
        if (tit != None):
            s = str(BeautifulSoup(str(tit), 'html.parser').get_text())
            gr = soup.body.find(size = "6", color = "#ff00ff")
            if (gr != None):
                s += str(BeautifulSoup(str(gr), 'html.parser').get_text())
            print(s)
            tlist = soup.findAll('p', align="CENTER")
            for tab in tlist:
                t = str(BeautifulSoup(str(tab), 'html.parser').get_text())
                t = t.strip()
                if t == '_':
                    t = '-'
                sl.append(t)
            for k in range(14, 92, 7):
                print("\n", sl[k])
                for i in range(7):
                    if(i == 0):
                        print(sl[i], " ", sl[i + 7], "        Предмет")
                    else:
                        print(sl[i], " ", sl[i + 7], " ", sl[i + k])
            sl.append(s)
    else:
        print("ERROR")
    return sl

cells = []
cells = cmp_parse(base_url, headres)

rows = []
for i in range(14, 92, 7):
    rows.append(cells[i:i+7])
lst = cells[98].split()

wb = xlwt.Workbook()
ws = wb.add_sheet(lst[0].strip() + ' ' + lst[4].strip())

columns = cells[0:7]
for i, col in enumerate(columns):
    ws.write(0, i, col)
    
clmns = cells[7:14]
for i, col in enumerate(clmns):
    ws.write(1, i, col)
ws.write(2, 0, "1-я неделя")

i = 3
for row in rows:
    for j, data in enumerate(row):
        ws.write(i, j, data)
    i += 1
    if(i == 9):
        ws.write(9, 0, "2-я неделя")
        i += 1

wb.save(lst[4] + '.xls')
```